# Is it possible to make a SQL statement, based on a single column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm struggling to write down an SQL statement for a query.

Basically, I want to select a record, based on a field, if this field is bigger than 0, then it should check if 1 hour is passed from a datetime field, if the field is lower or equal to 0 then it should ignore that check and just select it

In C# it would be something like this:

```
if (columnA > 0)
{ 
    //select if (columnB < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)))
    //if it's not match, move on to next record
} else {
    //just select it
}
```

So, in SQL what would be? Something like this:

```
SELECT field1, field2 
FROM table 
WHERE id = 1 
AND intLv < fieldLv 
AND IF (limitedLogin > 0) { lastLogin < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL time HOUR) AND logins < totLogins }
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

I'm not expert on SQL/MySQL statements, so I don't know if that is entirely possible. Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: You're looking for `where`, which is how you filter records based on various conditions.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, I want to select a record, based on a field, if this field is bigger than 0, then it should check if 1 hour is passed from a datetime field, if the field is lower or equal to 0 then it should ignore that check and just select it

You seem to be describing logic like this:

```
where columnA < 0 or
      columnB < now() - interval 1 hour;
```

Note:  This assumes that `= 0` is the same as `> 0`.

The first condition returns all rows where `columnA < 0`.  The second returns rows where column b is more than one hour ago.

Comment: I have edited my question with the problem, could you give it a check please? Thanks you so much

Comment: @FedeKindred . . . I have quoted the question asked in the original question.  This is the question answered here.

Comment: Ok but this is not working, it does not solve my question

Comment: the second statement, after the OR, will always be executed, no matter of the other results, then IF nothing is found for that statement, then it will search for the other. so ORDER BY is totally useless in the statement, as results will be ignored. While it should work the opposite way, the statement BEFORE the OR should be executed, not the contrary. however, inverting the statements, provoke the same behavior, thus not working

Comment: Either way, I open a new questions, there was not need to be rude.